# Wordpress website Thumbnails not showing on Facebook Share

Tags: facebook

When i am sharing my articles, it isn't showing featured image as a thumbnail. After using Facebook debugger, it is showing me this;

[image]

I also tried changing wordpress plugin settings as well as changed the featured image size, but still unable to fix it.

Comment: What is adding your Open Graph tag - is it a theme or a plugin? Find out what is adding the tag, and you can then research how to tell that theme or plugin to use the large size image instead of the 200x200.

Comment: I have plugins : SEO Press and WPsmush

Comment: Have you tried disabling the plugins to see whether the issue persists? If you turn them off, check, then turn on one at a time and check, you can find out if one of them is affecting the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
This issue was caused by two things;
1. Hotlink enable in Cpanel.
2. SEO Plugin

What i did;
1. Disabled "Hotlink Protection" from cPanel.
2. I changed my SEO Plugin. I was using SEOPress which caused issues and then i was shifted to Yoast SEO.